# password protect wordpress posts with custom post type by default

Tags: wordpress, password-protection, custom-post-type

i try to realize the following: posts with a custom post type should be password-protected by default

i found this which works great
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4952/forcing-all-posts-associated-with-a-custom-post-type-to-be-private

but i dont want the posts to be private so i chanced

```
$post->post_status = 'private';
$post->post_password = 'some_default_password';
```

to

```
$post->post_status = 'published';
$post->post_password = 'some_default_password';
```

but then there is no password protection

how can i get this done?

Comment: Will the CPT will **always** be password protected? And by *default* do you mean when the CPT is created ("Add new cpt")?

Comment: yes, when a post with a CPT is added, it should be password protected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code does this, but it only works when a new post (post_type) is created.

If we don't check for `empty($data['post_name'])`, which indicates that *a new post is being created*, it **locks** all posts with the `some_default_password` password.

<sup>Code based in this [WordPress StackExchange Q&A](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/54711/12615).</sup>

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'so_13517851_filter_handler' , '99', 2 );

function so_13517851_filter_handler( $data , $postarr ) 
{
    // creating new post and correct post_type
    if( empty( $data['post_name'] ) && 'post' == $postarr['post_type'] )
        $data[ 'post_password' ] = 'some_default_password';

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: i took the wp_insert_post_data and the thing with empty( $data['post_name'] ) and this works great. thank you